# Constructor for a Dictionary inside a Dictionary

Tags: c#

I am declaring a Dictionary inside a Dictionary like:

```
var something = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Object>>();
```

I want to be able to access both the outer dictionary as well as the inner dictionary with an IgnoreCase StringComparer.

```
var something = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Object>>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

As I am only calling the constructor of the outer dictionary, how can I set the StringComparer of the inner dictionary?  If I can't call it's constructor, I can see that there is a property `Comparer` but I'm not sure how I can get access to the inner dictionary object instead of just a Key or Value.

Any suggestions?

Comment: When you initialize the inner dictionary, you will call it's constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare:

```
var something = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Object>>();
```

It has not created any inner dictionary yet. You will initialize inner dictionary when you add data to it, e.g.

```
if(!something.ContainsKey("somekey"))
{
    something["somekey"] = new Dictionary<string, Object>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
}
```

Comment: Of course... don't know why I didn't think of that. Sorry for the Monday morning question -,-'

Comment: everybody needs a cup of coffee in Monday morning :)